# C++11 - how to approach this specific declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr

I have a some serious implementation dilemma. We all know doing something like this in example below is allowed in C++11 but `a` is not initialized so the result is also undefined:

```
int a = 5 + a;
```

However, I found this notation would be extremely meaningful to users of my open source project who are also providing a C++11 code. so I wanted to use it as API to my project. Please consider the following example:

```
Object name = upperCaseLetter & *(lowerCaseLetter | upperCaseLetter);
Object lowerCaseLetter = Object('a') - Object('z');
Object upperCaseLetter = Object('A') - Object('Z');
```

The above notation means that the `name` starts with upper case letter and is followed by (`&`) zero or more (`*`) lower or (`|`) upper case letters. The lower (or upper) case letter is a range (`-`) of characters.

Another example is:

```
Object number = (Object('0') - Object('9')) & !number;
```

The sign `!` means optional. So notation is similar to boost::spirit parser. However I encountered the problem in above declaration. When I am referring to `number` object it is not yet created. However object data is not accessed during initialization. So I wanted to use a pointer to that object. But when I used the pointer, for calls like `Object('0')`, object is created and then destroyed just after declaration. So pointer is invalid for that case. Later I tried to allocate all object data dynamically and to use shared pointer. However again, shared pointer of that `number` object is not yet initialized so it cannot be used. Also copying one object into another is wrong because as in above example we have recursion so it will fail in runtime.

Do you have any idea how to approach this problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: For the second case you're confusing digit and number. Your problem goes away when you clarify the distinction. Your first doesn't have a problem, just declare the stuff in the correct order.

Comment: So is `Object digit = (Object('0') - Object('9')) & !digit;` supposed to define an input where it will match a digit so long as it's not the same digit as before? Effectively throw away repetition?

Comment: Thank you, I corrected this!

Comment: You could distinguish between rvalues and lvalues by overloading your operators with rvalue- and lvalue-references, and decide from there whether to copy and store them or refer to them.

Comment: @Quentin, could you tell me a little bit more? I do not see this. Thanks!

Comment: @noonespecial: He's talking about ref qualified member functions

Comment: Wow, thank you guys! It looks like what I am looking for :)